# datepicker national holidays count

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have 2 inputs where dates are selected #startdate and #enddate. I am using datepicker and have currently disabled weekends and holidays, this is working great!

I then have a #days input which calculates the difference between the 2 dates, this date difference then has a weekend count taken from it.

I would like to create a holiday count so I can also minus this from the differnce in days.

So i would end up with

```
$('#days').val((Math.abs(($d2new-$d1new)/86400000) - weekend_count - holidaycount) + 1);
```

**My current code is as follows (this has been taken form other stackoverflow questions and is working great :)** towards the bottom is the var holidaycount which is what i am struggling with. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    //holidays
    var natDays = [
      [1, 1, 'uk'],
      [1, 2, 'uk'],
      [1, 3, 'uk'],
      [1, 4, 'uk'],
      [12, 24, 'uk'],
      [12, 25, 'uk'],
      [12, 26, 'uk'],
      [12, 27, 'uk'],
      [12, 28, 'uk'],
      [12, 29, 'uk'],
      [12, 30, 'uk'],
      [12, 31, 'uk']
    ];


    function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
        var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
        if (noWeekend[0]) {
            return nationalDays(date);
        } else {
            return noWeekend;
        }
    }
    function nationalDays(date) {
        for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
            if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1 && date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {
                return [false, natDays[i][2] + '_day'];
            }
        }
        return [true, ''];
    }



// do initialization here
$("#startdate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            yearRange: '0:+100',
            beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                $("#enddate").datepicker("option","minDate",selectedDate );
                $("#enddate2").datepicker("option","minDate",selectedDate );
            },              
            minDate: '+1d',         
            maxDate: '+' + DAY_DIFFERENCE + 'd'
});

// do initialization here
$("#enddate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            yearRange: '0:+100',
            beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
            maxDate: '+' + DAY_DIFFERENCE + 'd'
});

// do initialization here
$("#enddate2").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            yearRange: '0:+100',
            beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                $d1 = $('#startdate').val();
                $d2 = $('#enddate2').val();

                $myDateParts1 = $d1.split("-");
                $myDateParts2 = $d2.split("-");

                $d1flip = new Date($myDateParts1[2], ($myDateParts1[1]-1), $myDateParts1[0]);
                $d2flip = new Date($myDateParts2[2], ($myDateParts2[1]-1), $myDateParts2[0]);

                $newdate1 = $d1flip.format("ddd mmm dd hh:MM:ss yyyy");
                $newdate2 = $d2flip.format("ddd mmm dd hh:MM:ss yyyy");

                // For Opera and older winXP IE n such              
                $d1new  = Date.parse($newdate1);
                $d2new  = Date.parse($newdate2);

                var weekend_count = 0;
                    for (i = $d1new.valueOf(); i <= $d2new.valueOf(); i+= 86400000){
                    var temp = new Date(i);
                        if (temp.getDay() == 0 || temp.getDay() == 6) {
                            weekend_count++;
                        }
                }

                var holidaycount = 0;
                    for (i = $d1new.valueOf(); i <= $d2new.valueOf(); i+= 86400000){
                    var temp = new Date(i);
                        if (**date in var natDays & is in selected difference range**) {
                            holidaycount++;
                        }
                }


            console.log(weekend_count);
            console.log(holidaycount);

                $('#days').val((Math.abs(($d2new-$d1new)/86400000) - weekend_count - holidaycount) + 1);
            }           
});


}, 'html');
return false;
});
}
```

**EDIT**

From the answer, I have inserted the function and tried this....
console.log(holidaycount); returns 0 but with the chosen dates i selected it should have been 10

```
            var holidaycount = 0;
                for (i = $d1new.valueOf(); i <= $d2new.valueOf(); i+= 86400000){
                var temp = new Date(i);
                    if (isHoliday(temp)) {
                        holidaycount++;
                }                       
                }
```

Comment: @ManseUK what happens when it runs? Well, `if (**date in var natDays & is in selected difference range**)` is probably not a valid JS condition (you know, it's _towards the bottom_ where there _is the var holidaycount which is what [he is] struggling with_). Just saying ;)

Comment: According to your edit, you're calling isHoliday with only one argument (missing argument `country`), and if you copied/pasted the function I wrote then you never pass the test `country.toLowerCase() == natDays[i][2].toLowerCase()`. If it still doesn't work, I suggest you provide a jsFiddle or the like so that we can test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: modified `getMonth()` to `getMonth() + 1` accordingly to the comments.

```
**date in var natDays & is in selected difference range**
```

*date is in selected difference range* is always true as `new Date(i)` is inside said range (just like in the loop for `weekend_count`: you didn't bother with checking whether you're in the range).

Now, checking if the date inside `temp` is a holiday, you may want to use a function (though you still can do it straight in your code):

```
/* dateObject is a JS Date object (e.g. dateObject = new Date();) */
/* country is the country we test holidays for */
function isHoliday(dateObject, country) {
  /* let's assume natDays is global, otherwise pass it as a third argument to this function */
  for(var i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
    /* natDays[i][0] is a day, natDays[i][1] is a month, natDays[i][2] is a country indicator */
    if(parseInt(dateObject.getDate()) == parseInt(natDays[i][0]) && parseInt(dateObject.getMonth()) + 1 == parseInt(natDays[i][1]) && country.toLowerCase() == natDays[i][2].toLowerCase()) {
      /* found a day and a month matching our current Date's day and month: interrupt and tell caller dateObject is a holiday */
      return true;
    }
  }
  /* end of loop, we parsed all possible holidays without finding any match for our Date: tell caller the given Date is not a holiday */
  return false;
}
```

Now to put it in your code:

```
if (isHoliday(temp, 'uk')) {
  holidaycount++;
}
```

This should do the trick, though it may require some refactoring (did not test this code), and there is probably more elegant ways to do it (like modding the Date object's prototype to use this function as a method of the object).

Comment: thanks for the answer although i have implemented this console.log(holidaycount); returns 0. I have updated my question with what im  using from your code

Comment: got it woking :) thank you ------------- FYI if(parseInt(dateObject.getDate()) == parseInt(natDays[i][1]) && parseInt(dateObject.getMonth() + 1) == parseInt(natDays[i][0])) { ------------------it was the month because 0 = jan etc and the month and days were wrong way round

Comment: Good to know, I updated my answer. Would you please mark this answer as the good one if there's nothing more? Enjoy the holidays ;)